# Error:Module 'app': platform 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:23' not found

Tags: android, gradle, google-api, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Gradle file:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:23'
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.1'
```

It works perfectly in other Windows machine, but in this computer it gives this error: `Error:Module 'app': platform 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:23' not found.`

I need to compile with `Google APIs:23` instead of `SDK 23` because I'm using some things that are in Google APIs add-on.

I checked that some solutions here in Stack Overflow tell that you can avoid this problem changing my Gradle file to `compileSdkVersion 23`, but it is not a good solution because if you do that you are not compiling using Google APIs add-ons.

Both AndroidStudios and AndroidSDKs are fully updated in both machines, so I can't understand why I'm getting this error only in one of them.

Answer (score 2):

Finally I got it working.

1. Rename your line from compileSdkVersion `'Google Inc.:Google APIs:23'` to `compileSdkVersion 23`
2. Build project, it should work (but supossedly without google apis add-ons)
3. Rename again your line from `compileSdkVersion 23` to `'Google Inc.:Google APIs:23'`.
4. Build project.
5. If it does not work, try downloading Google APIs:23 add-on from command line tool `sdkmanager` and repeat the process.

Answer (score 0):

[From google's github:](https://github.com/google/google-api-java-client)

> If you are developing for Android and the Google API you want to use is included in the [Google Play Services](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup) library, you should use that library for the best performance and experience.

So check first if the Google API you need is included in play services or not. If yes then use that. If you need to use other Google APIs, then you can find the setup instructions [here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/android).

And finally, [here's an example project](https://github.com/google/google-api-java-client-samples/blob/master/calendar-android-sample/build.gradle) from google that uses the `google play services` library and the other Google APIs outside of play services:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-calendar:v3-rev260-1.23.0' exclude module: 'httpclient'
    compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.23.0' exclude module: 'httpclient'
    compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-gson:1.23.0' exclude module: 'httpclient'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:7.3.0'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"
    .
    .
}
```